# Python Web Scraping - Email notification when there is an error

Tags: python, email, alert, sendgrid

I've been given some web scraping code on Python and now need to write some code so that if there is an error, it will notify someone by email. I have found this code online:

```
def send_email():
    to = request.form.get('to')
    if not to:
        return ('Please provide an email address in the "to" query string '
                'parameter.'), 400

    sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=SENDGRID_API_KEY)

    to_email = mail.Email(to)
    from_email = mail.Email(SENDGRID_SENDER)
    subject = 'This is a test email'
    content = mail.Content('text/plain', 'Example message.')
    message = mail.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)

    response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=message.get())

    if response.status_code != 202:
        return 'An error occurred: {}'.format(response.body), 500

    return 'Email sent.'
```

Is this the kind of thing that I should use? If not, what is the best way to go about this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the above code run well for you? If yes, you may jsut call that function in the except block of your previous scrapping code.

Comment: What type of Error in web scarping?

Answer (score 0):

What I meant:

```
try: 
     # Web scrapping code    
except requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError as e:
     print repr(e)
     send_email()
```

**OR**

use `except` without specifying for passive handling.

```
try: 
     # Web scrapping code    
except:
     send_email()
```

**BUT:**

[From the PEP-8 Style Guide for Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> When catching exceptions, mention specific exceptions whenever
>   possible instead of using a bare except: clause.
>
> A bare except: clause will catch SystemExit and KeyboardInterrupt
>   exceptions, making it harder to interrupt a program with Control-C,
>   and can disguise other problems. If you want to catch all exceptions
>   that signal program errors, use except Exception: (bare except is
>   equivalent to except BaseException:).
>
> A good rule of thumb is to limit use of bare 'except' clauses to two
>   cases:
>
> If the exception handler will be printing out or logging the
>   traceback; at least the user will be aware that an error has occurred.
>   If the code needs to do some cleanup work, but then lets the exception
>   propagate upwards with raise. try...finally can be a better way to
>   handle this case.